# Combining a list into a string

Tags: python-3.x

I am working on some code that should alter a string to create a new line when certain requirements are met. However, since I alter the string to be a list it prints as a list in the end, and I do not know how to turn the list into a string or analyse the string by leaving it as a string. Furthermore I would also greatly appreciate if someone could explain why the addition of "\n" does not actually create a line break.

I have tried `str(variable)` to turn the list into a string, however this doesn't seem to work. Furthermore, I have tried changing appending methods to see if that would actually insert a line break; `variable.append`, `+=`, but these all don't seem to work. I am new to Python and programming and am struggling.

```
    sentence= "Hello. My name is George... Michael! David Browns."
    def sentence_splitter(target_sentence):
        target_sentence = list(target_sentence)
        for character in range(len(target_sentence)):
            if target_sentence[character:character+2] == list(". ") or target_sentence[character:character+2] == list("! "):
                target_sentence[character:character+2] += list("\n")
        print(str(target_sentence))
```

sentence_splitter(sentence)

Current Result:

```
['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '.', ' ', '\n', 'M', 'y', ' ', 'n', 'a', 'm', 'e', ' ', 'i', 's', ' ', 'G', 'e', 'o', 'r', 'g', 'e', '.', '.', '.', ' ', '\n', 'M', 'i', 'c', 'h', 'a', 'e', 'l', '!', ' ', '\n', 'D', 'a', 'v', 'i', 'd', ' ', 'B', 'r', 'o', 'w', 'n', 's', '.']
```

Expected Result:

```
Hello.

My name is George...

Michael!

David Browns.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`target_sentence` is a list. Use `print(''.join(target_sentence))` instead of `print(str(target_sentence))` to combine all the elements of the list into a string.

Output:

```
Hello.
My name is George...
Michael!
David Browns.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sent = ""
for i in sentence.split(" "):
    sent = sent + " " + i
    if i[-1] in ['.', '!']:
        sent = sent + "\n"

print(sent)
```

OUTPUT:

```
 Hello.
 My name is George...
 Michael!
 David Browns.
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, this is also a very useful approach which I can generalize to other rules.